# Django 1.7 Installed app Import Error

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an app on django 1.7.1

I recently created a VM to setup a development server and moved my app to that VM (my machine was Open SUSE and the VM is CentOS7)

After set up the database and the python packages I run the migration and run the server. The server start without any problem

The problem is when I try to run my script to populate the DB.

I load the settings

```
sys.path.append('/home/evtdb/FLWeb/FLWeb')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

django.setup()
```

but i got this error

```
  File "scripts/populate_database.py", line 14, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  **ImportError: No module named events**
```

The settings.py  include the events app on INSTALLED APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'events',
    'dh5bp',
    'django_tables2',
)
```

The apps.py  and the **init**.py are also set up

**events/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class EventsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'events'
    verbose_name = "Events"
```

**events/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'events.apps.EventsConfig'
```

I don't know why the server can start running but not the script

Answer (score 0):

events app doesn't look like a Django app, did you tried to create one using `manage.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Django 1.7, but I got that error because I was using Django 1.5. Once I upgrade to Django 1.9, the problem is solved. It turns out, module `django.apps` is not available in the older version of Django.